# On change event on the selection of dropdown's value using underscore and backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I created the dynamic dropdown in template. and my further requirement is to change the value of the dropdown and send the value back to the web service to hit to change in the system. I have no idea how to do it in underscore template. below is the code that i write for dynamic dropdown. and where have to write the ratecall function either in template file or in main.js no idea about it. and rightnow I am just firing an alert showing on change fired but its not working. actually the error that is coming is ratecall is not defined. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
  <select id="rate" onchange="ratecall()">
                    <% for(var i=0;i<post.scales-1;i++){
                         if(i==post.rated){
                         var a= 'selected';
                         }else{
                         a='';
                         }
                         %>
                         <option id="<%=i%>"<%=a %> > <%= i%></option>
                        <%}%> 
                </select>
                <%}else{
                }
                function ratecall(){
                document.getElementById("rate").onchange = function () {
                alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");
                };
                }
```

Comment: why you have put `funcion inside another function?` there is no need to do it.. may be **this will go into a infinite loop**..
only put `function ratecall(){alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");}`

Comment: yes I have been tried your suggestion too but it is not working in any case.

Comment: Actually I error that seems is ratecall function is undefined.

Comment: try **defining your function before you call it**... I mean put your function before `select` tag.. and I dont know more about `backbone.js or underscore.js` but dont you need to put your function in a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag???

Comment: As this is backbone, your event should really be handling your events within your view. Your template should only be responsible for the structure of the HTML, not adding inline references to other Javascript functions.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @danblundell in the comments, the view should be responsible only for rendering.
I made a minimal backbone example which illustrates how it's done (for your example): http://jsfiddle.net/dh64x/3/

Backbone provides view objects where you can specify events and event handlers:

```
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'change #rate': 'postSelected'
    },

    // ...

    postSelected: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

In this case, change events on select#rate element are bound to `postSelected` function.

Read the docu for more details:
http://backbonejs.org/#View

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code..

```
<select id="rate" onchange="ratecall()">
<%
for(var i = 0;i < post.scales - 1;i++)
{
var a= ''
if(i==post.rated)
    {
       a = 'selected';
    }
    else
    {
        a = '';
    }
%>
<option id="<%= i %>" <%= a %> > <%= i %></option>
<% } %> 
</select>
<%

function ratecall()
{ 
         alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");       
}
```